# Live server is not loading my images but when I open my file manually ex:index.html, my images are fully loaded

Tags: html

```
<div class="slide__Show1">
       <h2>It's More Than Just A Sport</h2>
       <p>Get back on the field in style!</p>
       <img src='../E-commerce/IMG/Soccer.jpeg'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live server works as a real (remote) server, and looks for the image like a real server would do: Not on your local machine, but relative to the project root on your "server".

When you open a local HTML file on your computer/in your browser, it is able to look for the image file locally anywhere on your computer, and thus is a bit easier to satisfy.

So there's a slight difference which types of URLs/paths you can use in a local file and a file that is supposed to work on a server.

In your case, you need to use either an absolute path or a relative path.

- Absolute path: `https://examplesite.com/assets/img/soccer.jpg`
- Relative path: `/assets/img/soccer.jpg`

Your relative path goes one level UP (out) from the root folder of your project (because of `../`)  and searches for a file that is probably outside your website folder, in the E-commerce directory.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Alright so the main file is called 'Code' and the secondary file is 'E-commerce' and inside is my 'image' and index.html. What would be the best format in order the work on both?

Comment: Do you mean directories instead of "file" here? Is your main directory `Code/` and inside of it there is an `E-commerce/` directory with the image in? As long as E-commerce is inside the root folder of your project, index.html will be able to find it. So maybe tell us more about your folder structure and I'll answer what you need to do.

Comment: Yes, on my desktop there is the Code, inside there is my e-commerce file and inside there is my index.html and my CSS and a separate folder for 'image'.

Comment: So if I understand your structure correctly then your image tag could be this: `<img src="/E-commerce/image/soccer.jpg" alt="Description of a soccer photo" title="Title for a soccer image" width="123" height="456">` . Note that uppercase/lowercase matters. So if the folder is called `e-commerce` it won't work with `E-commerce`. Same goes for the image folder name and the jpg file name.

Comment: Thank you so much! It now works with the live server but doesn't work when I normally open my 'index.html'. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can remove the slash `/` in front of the E-commerce directory name, and it should start working both ways. But I recommend that you always use LiveServer or similar, because it's the most realistic way of developing (and less tedious than doing manual refreshes). Using that slash in front makes it clearer where in the folder hierarchy you are. I also noted that you use single quotes around the image, use double quotes always in HTML (single quotes is used in JavaScript and other languages).